# Dynamics CRM 365 - update fields using any unique field except GUID field

Tags: c#, httprequest, dynamics-crm, dotnet-httpclient, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to update `Contact` entity's `firstname` field using `PATCH` / `PUT` using `HttpClient`.

I have tried this using `PATCH` with contact's `GUID`. But if I try the same with below URL:

> baseURL/contacts(myorg_contactnumber='113')
>
> baseURL/contacts('113')
>
> baseURL/contacts(myorg_contactnumber="113")

but it is throwing `Bad Request` error.

Comment: You need to setup alternate key on contact entity to be able, and use that key name to reference the contact record.

Comment: Please include code for making this request.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, like Jatin said - probably only miss could be [Alternate key setup](http://www.oak3.org/crm/using-alternate-keys-webapi/).

> The nice thing with the PATCH request like this is, that by default it will update the *record* if it exists, or it will create the *record* if it doesn’t exist.

```
url: /api/data/v8.2/contacts(new_alternatekey='12345')
method: PATCH
body: {
    "name": "Alternate key contact updated"
}
```

Also you tagged C#, so try something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt770369.aspx):

```
   JObject contact1Add = new JObject();
   contact1Add.Add("firstname", "Jack");

   HttpRequestMessage updateRequest1 = new HttpRequestMessage(
       new HttpMethod("PATCH"), contact1Uri);
   updateRequest1.Content = new StringContent(contact1Add.ToString(),
       Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   HttpResponseMessage updateResponse1 =
       await httpClient.SendAsync(updateRequest1);
   if (updateResponse1.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent) //204
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Contact '{0} {1}' updated with " +
        "firstname", contact1.GetValue("firstname"),
        contact1.GetValue("lastname"));
   }
   else
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to update contact for reason: {0}",
        updateResponse1.ReasonPhrase);
    throw new CrmHttpResponseException(updateResponse1.Content);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GUID but don't put in quotes.
I used this
basurl/api/data/v9.2/entityname(12ab2389-8831-e111-02f0f0fb9999)/
Where that is a guid not in quotes and it works fine.
Dynamics uses ODATA so that helps to look up things there and you can get entity names and fields names using the ODATA metadata request.